# Formula of Linear Mixed Effect Model

Tags: mixed-model

I would like to perform a regression between two variables and I was
wondering if the formula I am using is actually correct.

In an experiment, participants had to adjust two parameters of a provided sound in order to match their body weight. I want to find if their choices of those parameters (let's call them Param_1 and Param_2) were related to their actual weight.

In the experiment there were 12 different stimuli and each stimulus was repeated twice. The experiment was performed by 18 subjects.

Given this design with repeated measures I have used a linear mixed effects model.

Firstly for each stimulus I considered only the corresponding subset of the data (since the two parameters had different ranges for each Stimulus):

```r
Stimulus_1 <- subset(scrd, Stimulus == "Stimulus_1")
```

Afterwards I used this formula:

```r
library(nlme)
summary(lme(Param_1 ~ Weight, data = Stimulus_1, 
                              random = ~1 | Subject))
```

And this is the output

```r
Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML
 Data: Concrete_sn 
       AIC      BIC    logLik
  106.2133 112.3188 -49.10667

Random effects:
 Formula: ~1 | Subject
        (Intercept)  Residual
StdDev:   0.3097865 0.8037759

Fixed effects: Param_1 ~ Weight 
                 Value Std.Error DF  t-value p-value
(Intercept) 0.07859641 0.7686462 18 0.102253  0.9197
Weight      0.03064528 0.0110516 16 2.772922  0.0136
 Correlation: 
       (Intr)
Weight -0.98 

Standardized Within-Group Residuals:
       Min         Q1        Med         Q3        Max 
-1.3529280 -0.5313141 -0.1803727  0.2964860  3.0365480 

Number of Observations: 36
Number of Groups: 18
```

As you can see, I only randomized the Subject, not the repetition ... is this correct right?

If I am not wrong, from the output I can notice that participant's choices of Param_1 depended by their body weight, since the p-value is below 0.05.

Comment: It seems you are asking for an analysis strategy for a complex experiment. This is something you would normally hire a statistical consultant for (once you know how to do the analysis, any programmer can do it). In any case, more context might be helpful.
For example: It seems you are only analysing stimulus 1 for the moment. Without knowing more about the setup, it is difficult to assess whether or not this is a good idea. You can add a random effect for repetition as well - do you expect the results to change with repetitions?

Comment: Hi Rob, no I do not expect the results to change with repetitions. I am analyzing all stimuli, but I am performing the analysis separately for each stimulus. Which kind of additional information you need to understand if it is a good idea or not?

Comment: The short answer is: if you are convinced that this is the right analysis strategy, then yes, seeing a p-value less than 0.05 may be considered a significant result. As you do not expect any changes with repetition (due to your knowledge of how the experiment works), I'd say you would be free to leave that out (more cautious statisticians might want to put it in).